# How to Implement and Process @Terser

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-camel, hapi, hl7-v2

Currently I am working with HL7 for Healthcare Interoperability with Apache Camel 2.13.2 & Apache Hapi. While I trying to write new Meta Data Annotation `@Terser` and customized processor, suddenly eclipse auto suggestion break my concentration. I found there `@org.apache.camel.component.hl7.Terser` annotation already exist. Since that time I am trying but unable to use it as no example found by Camel Docs as well as Googling. If any body have an implementation of such type of code would you like to kind enough to help me.

Comment: https://github.com/KingsCollegeHospital/rassyeyanie/blob/master/camel-hl7/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/hl7/TerserExpressionTest.java

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that class is an annotation, despite what Eclipse is trying to tell you. The Terser class is described  in http://camel.apache.org/hl7.html